# Install netbeans from a local computer to a remote workstation

Tags: ssh, remote, netbeans

I've downloaded the netbans.sh file from its official website and I'd like to install it to some workstations without having to copy it in any of those workstations.

Can I remotely ssh connect and install the sh program without having to copy the program to any single workstation?

Answer (score 0):

The .sh file is not a program, but a shell script.

Could you explain why don't you want to copy the installation script on the remote workstations?